# Render charts based on type with AngularJS components

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, highcharts

I got a really strange problem with Highcharts in combination with Angularjs 1.6. I am using components to render graphs based on the chart type. This is a example of my json data:

```
 "Widgets":[  
  {  
     "Id":1,
     "description":"Test test",
     "datasource":"Risk",
     "charttype":"Bar",
     "x":0,
     "y":0,
     "width":3,
     "height":2
  },
  {  
     "Id":2,
     "description":"test test 2",
     "datasource":"KRI",
     "charttype":"Area",
     "x":3,
     "y":0,
     "width":3,
     "height":2
  },
  {  
     "Id":3,
     "description":"Some cool data",
     "datasource":"KRI",
     "charttype":"Heatmap",
     "x":6,
     "y":0,
     "width":3,
     "height":2
  }
]
```

Based on **Charttype** I want to render the charts and I am using angular components for this. This is my angular component for a Bar chart:

```
angular.module("generalApp").component("chartType", {
template: "<div class=Bar></div>",
bindings: {
    data: "=",
    charttype: "="
},
controller: function () {
  $('.Bar').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    })
} 
});
```

And this is a component for my Area chart

```
angular.module("generalApp").component("chartType", {
template: "<div class=Area></div>",
bindings: {
    data: "=",
    charttype: "="
},
controller: function () {
    $('.Area').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
}
});
```

On the HTML page I use the custom tag to use the component:

```
<chart-type data="w.datasource" charttype="w.charttype"></chart-type>
```

I want to bind the charttype on the widgets and based on that it must render a chart:

Condition

```
ng-repeat="w in dashboard.Widgets track by $index"
```

When I only use one chart it's working fine but when I use a more then component I get the following error in my console.

[image: Console error]

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that all of your components are registered using the name `chartType`. 
They all should have a unique name, for instance: `BarComponent` and `AreaComponent`.

In your container template you can include all of the chart type components. And with a control flow directive you can specify what component should be displayed to the user. For example:

```
<div ng-switch="currentComponent">
  <area-component ng-switch-when="area"></area-component>
  <bar-component ng-switch-when="bar"></bar-component>
  <div ng-switch-default>Please select a chart type</div>
</div>
```